# How to save image to application path and retrieve from application path

Tags: vb.net

I have one project and in this project I want to save picture to application path and save the path to database as string and retrieve the image from the application path.
Can u give me some idea about it...
i am using vb.net as frontend and ms access database

Comment: @Biswo: you should accept answers of your previous questions

Comment: Is it ASP.NET or WinForms application?

Comment: @Darin: With Access as a backend I really hope it is a WinForms-Application...

Answer (score 2):

Getting the Application Path:

```
My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

Combining Paths:

```
[System.IO.]Path.Combine(Path1, Path2)
```

Images:

```
yourImageObject.Save(yourPath)
yourImageObject = Image.FromFile(yourPath)
```